# ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.7

Hola estoy haciendo una animación de un semi-circulo utilizando la librería de matplotlib animation, la ecuación del semi-circulo es y=sqrt(r**2-x**2), sin embargo cuando los valors de x son negativos, es decir, la raíz sería imaginaria y me genera el error de math domain. ¿Como podría arreglar este error?

Este es el codígo

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import math as mth

x=[]
y=[]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 105)
ax.set_ylim(0, 12)
line, = ax.plot(0,0)

def animacion(i):
      r=5
      x.append(i**2)
      y.append(mth.sqrt((r**2)-(i**2)))

      line.set_xdata(x)
      line.set_ydata(y)
      return line,

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animacion , frames= np.arange(0,30, 0.01), interval = 1)
plt.show()
```

En adición como podría hacer que se graficar el semi-circulo con un radio variante haciendo que el semi circulo se expandiera en función del radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunas observaciones:

- para evitar coger la raíz de un número negativo, se puede añadir un test, y solo calcular la raíz si el número es positivo
- añadiendo `i**2` a la lista `x`, se obtendrá un círculo muy deformado; mejor añadir `i`
- con `set_aspect('equal')` ambos ejes tendrán las mismas distancias; así se puede ver un circulo redondo en vez de un elipse.
- con `set_xlim(0, 105)` el eje `x` es muy larga, y solo hay algo interesante entre 0 y 5, casi invisible
- calculando `y` como `yc + sqrt((r ** 2) - ((i - xc) ** 2))` permite tener en cuenta el centro del círculo; sino el centro seria `0,0` y con el `x` empezando a `0` solo se ve un cuarto de círculo
- poniendo los frames en pasos de `0.01`, la diferencia entre pasos es super corta; en el código abajo esta puesto a `0.1`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

x = []
y = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 30)
ax.set_ylim(0, 12)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
line, = ax.plot(0, 0)

def animacion(i):
    r = 5
    xc = 0  # centro
    yc = 0
    y2 = (r ** 2) - ((i - xc) ** 2)
    if y2 >= 0:
        x.append(i)
        y.append(yc + np.sqrt(y2))
    line.set_xdata(x)
    line.set_ydata(y)
    return line,

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animacion, frames=np.arange(0, 30, 0.1), repeat=False, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda (y)

Comment: Ya pude solucionar el problema haciendo el semicirculo con cos y sin en funcion de tetha.